# Click on chart to activate hyperlink EXCEL

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, hyperlink

Is it possible to use a mouse click on a chart to trigger a hyperlink ?

*(the hyperlink will be to a place within the document)*

It can be done on images and shapes, so can this also be done on charts ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out you can (at least in Excel 2016).

1. Select your chart
2. Insert > Links > Insert Link (bottom of your list) opens the standard Insert Hyperlink dialog box
3. Place in this document will allow you to choose a cell reference or defined name.

Comment: Hi, I am trying this method, however Link is 'greyed' out on the insert tab when any chart is selected, I am using 2016

Comment: Make sure you're selecting the Chart Area (outermost part), and not the plot area, or any other internal piece.  Choosing any of those other areas grays out Links for me also.