# Turning Excel Graphs into buttons

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to turn excel graphs into buttons or links to the spread sheet where the graph is generated. Is this possible and if so how do you do it?

Answer (score 0):

#### I'm trying to turn excel graphs into buttons or links. Is this possible and if so how do you do it?

Chart sheets do not have a cell to attach a hyperlink to. However, you can do the following:

**Excel 2016**

> - Select your chart
> - Insert > Links > Insert Link (bottom of your list) opens the standard Insert Hyperlink dialog box
> - Place in this document will allow you to choose a cell reference or defined name.

Source [Click on chart to activate hyperlink EXCEL](https://superuser.com/a/1323537/337631), answer by [Dav](https://superuser.com/users/126544/dav)

**Older versions of Excel (2007, 2003 and earlier)**

> - Insert a text box on your chart (in Excel 2003 and earlier, text boxes can be located on the Drawing toolbar, whereas in Excel 2007 it
>     can be inserted from the ‘Insert’ tab of the Ribbon, in the ‘Text’
>     group, ALT + N + X);
> - Type in the text you want and make it appear to look like a hyperlink by formatting the text (e.g. colour blue and underline);
> - Right hand click on the text box and choose ‘Assign Macro…’ from the shortcut menu [N.B. Excel 2007 users: ensure ‘Developer’ tab is
>     available and visible before proceeding, see below];
> - Type a name for the macro and then press the ‘Record’ button;
> - Select the worksheet and cell you want your “pseudo-hyperlink” to jump to;
> - Stop the macro using the ‘Stop’ button (Excel 2003 and earlier) / ‘Stop Recording’ button (on the ‘Developer’ tab in the ‘Code’ group).
>     [N.B. If the ‘Developer’ tab is not visible, use ALT + T + O to go to
>     the ‘Popular’ Excel Options and check the third check box, ‘Show
>     Developer tab in the Ribbon’.]

Source [Hyperlinking Chart Sheets](https://www.sumproduct.com/thought/hyperlinking-chart-sheets)